# uncaught handler: tread main exiting due to uncaught exception ( basically a NULL pointer exception)

Tags: android

I am basically trying to use the alarmclock code and make some changes to it.
I got the 2.0 code from net and my emulator is 2.1,

Now, the compilation errors are all solved, But when I run the app in the emulator, then it throws the error " the app has stopped unexpectedly. plz try again" in the emulator

and in the Logcat i get the following error:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception              
java.lang.NullPointerException                                               
at android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(DateFormat.java:204)      
at com.alarmclock.rafia.Alarms.get24HourMode(Alarms.java:518)              
at com.alarmclock.rafia.DigitalClock.setDateFormat(DigitalClock.java:208)  
at com.alarmclock.rafia.DigitalClock.onFinishInflate(DigitalClock.java:121)
```

The exact files of my code is here: in this line return android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/packages/apps/AlarmClock/src/com/android/alarmclock/Alarms.java

and in this function:     setDateFormat();
in this file: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/packages/apps/AlarmClock/src/com/android/alarmclock/DigitalClock.java

Please help I am stuck :(

Comment: use `Context context` instead of `final Context context` every where maybe helpful

Comment: ok, lemme try. thanks, how does it help? sorry i am new to android, if its a silly Q

Comment: i'm also searching for `mContext` variable in in given links but i'm not able to find where is it so plz use `DigitalClock.this.` instead of `mContext`

Comment: ok try it if not solved then tell me i will send you running code link.

Comment: Hi.. Please do send me the running code link. It will help a lot. Thanks in advance..

Comment: these are the lines where mcontext is used in the code in digitalclock
    mContext.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);
       mContext.unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
    mContext.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(
                mFormatChangeObserver);
    mFormat = Alarms.get24HourMode(mContext) ? Alarms.M24 : M12;
        mAmPm.setShowAmPm(mFormat == M12);

If i use  DigitalClock.this, then I cant access the above methods

Comment: when i was using the code from the netmite link, i was getting an error, mContext cannot be resolved.
So I created a variable, "Context mContext" to solve this compilation error, After that I was getting the exception, can you tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Context mContext = getContext();
had to initialise the mContext variable, and it got solved